# How can we rearrange a table with bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I have some ascii file like:

```
color  green
color  black
color  yellow
os     Linux
os     android
os     windows
os     mac
drink  coffee
drink  water
number 1
number 0
number 100
```

I want to make a table something like:

```
color   os       drink      number
-----------------------------------
green   Linux    coffee     1
black   android  water      0
yellow  windows             100
        mac
```

I wrote this code and it does what I want.
Are there some better solutions?

```
#!/bin/bash

inpfile=$1
keys=$(cat $inpfile | cut -d" " -f 1 | uniq)
for key in $keys
do
    values=$(cat $inpfile | grep $key | cut -d" " -f 2)
    result=$(echo "$key ----- $values")
    echo $result | datamash -W transpose > /tmp/$key.table
done

paste -d "\t" /tmp/*.table
rm /tmp/*.table
```

Comment: `cat | grep | cut` is an anti-pattern.  Instead of `cat "$inpfile" | grep "$key" | cut -d" " -f 2`, just write `awk 'match($0, p){print $2}' p="$key"`  If the keys are simple, you can get often away with `awk "/$key/{print \$2}"`

Answer (score 2):

The shell script in your question would fail given various input values (substrings, regexp metachars, spaces, etc.) and/or environment settings and/or even the contents of the directory you run it from. Copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues. It'll also be extremely slow.

Here's how to do it robustly, efficiently, and portably using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
!($1 in tag2colNr) {
    tag2colNr[$1] = ++numCols
    rowNr = ++numVals[numCols]
    vals[rowNr,numCols] = $1
}
{
    colNr = tag2colNr[$1]
    rowNr = ++numVals[colNr]
    vals[rowNr,colNr] = $2
    numRows = (numVals[colNr]>numRows ? numVals[colNr] : numRows)
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
color   os      drink   number
green   Linux   coffee  1
black   android water   0
yellow  windows         100
        mac
```

There are various ways to add the line of dashes under the tags (header) line and/or change the spacing between fields if you feel there's some value in it but since you said "I want to make a table **something like**..." I assume the above is like enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using [tput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

function handleFile() {
    local data_file="${1}"
    local x=0
    local y=0
    local column_width=20

    # we are using tput below to place the cursor,
    # so clear the screen for clean output.
    clear

    while read -r header ; do
        # each header is a new column so reset y coordinate to 0
        y=0

        # place header with underline
        printf "$(tput cup "${y}" "${x}")$(tput smul)%s$(tput sgr0)" "${header}"

        while read -r row ; do
            # move down 1 row by incrementing y coordinate value
            ((y+=1))

            # place the current row value without underline
            printf "$(tput cup "${y}" "${x}")%s$(tput sgr0)" "${row}"

        # get row values for each header using grep/awk
        done < <(grep "${header}" "${data_file}" | awk '{ print $2 }')

        # move to next column by incrementing x coordinate by desired column width
        ((x+=column_width))

    # use awk/sort to get unique header values
    done < <(awk '{ print $1 }' "${data_file}" | sort -u)

    # move cursor down 2 lines and then remove all cursor settings
    ((y+=2)) && tput cup "${y}" 0 && tput sgr0
}

handleFile "$@"
```

Sample usage is:

```
./script.sh data.txt

color               drink               number              os
green               coffee              1                   Linux
black               water               0                   android
yellow                                  100                 windows
                                                            mac
```